# How to delete Duplicate Nodes based on title?

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there any easy way to remove duplicate nodes based on Node title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by [Remove Duplicates](https://www.drupal.org/project/remove_duplicates) module

> This module helps the administrator to easily remove duplicate nodes according to one of the node fields.
>
> **Features**
>
> The duplicate nodes found are permanently removed. It can be very useful with Drupal Feeds module ([Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds)).

Comment: hw can i test this..

Comment: actually i jst create some content i.e. Article with same name... all are shows...

Comment: @niks88 I didn't try this module before let me check that for you

Comment: @niks88 It's working fine. Once ***Remove Duplicates*** module is installed and enabled,
you can use it at admin/config/content/remove_duplicates. If you not sure, please try it on your local env.

Comment: after enable is there any setting is needed...???

Comment: @niks88 No need,For any contib modul please follow **Readme** file under module directory

Comment: please help... i want to display some Users with there posts & i want to make pagination in there posts. Actually i created Users & Posts Table In mysql. How can i fetch both & use pagination in posts/comments ?? @Krishna Mohan

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve that by creating a custom module

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Remove Duplicate Nodes.
 */
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function dedupe_menu() {
    $items['admin/content/dedupe'] = array(
        'title' => 'Dedupe',
        'description' => 'Delete Duplicate Nodes',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('dedupe_content_command'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
    return $items;
}
/**
 * Build Form
 */
function dedupe_content_command() {
    $options = node_get_types('names');
    $form['dedupe_node_types'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('You can select content type from which duplicates are removed.'),
        '#options' => $options,
        '#default_value' => variable_get('dedupe_node_types', array('page')),
        '#description' => t('Duplicate content from the selected content types will be deleted.'),
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Dedupe'),
    );
    return $form;
}
/**
 * Call delete function and set message.
 */
function dedupe_content_command_submit($form, $form_state) {
    $type= $form_state['values']['dedupe_node_types'];
    $dedupe_m = 'Duplicates deleted from content type '. $type;
    dedupe_delete($type);
    drupal_set_message(check_plain(t($dedupe_m)));
}
/**
 * Delete duplicates from selected content type, based on title. By Robert Douglass.
 * @see http://robshouse.net/blog-post/remove-duplicate-nodes-dedupe-based-title
 */
function dedupe_delete($type) {
    $previous = array();
    $result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node}
    WHERE title IN
      (SELECT title FROM {node}
        WHERE type = '%s'
        GROUP BY title HAVING count(*) > 1)
    ORDER BY title, created DESC", $type);
    while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($row['title'] == $previous['title']) {
            node_delete($previous['nid']);
        }
        $previous = $row;
    }
}
?>
```

Note: I didn't test this code.But seems it would work.Read more from [Remove Duplicate Nodes based on title](https://www.drupal.org/node/720190)